# SPOJ: What is the difference between these two answers for KURUK14

Tags: c++

I have solved [this](http://www.spoj.com/problems/KURUK14/) problem and got AC. My problem is related to equivalence of following two approaches. The first code got accepted, while the second didn't.
As far as I can discern, both are completely equivalent for all the (valid) test cases any human can think of. Am I wrong? If so, what test case can differentiate them?

Code#1 (Accepted one):

```
#include <cstdio>

bool* M;

bool proc(int N){
    for(int j=0;j<=N;j++){
        M[j]=false;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
        int a=0;
        scanf("%d",&a);
        if(a>=N)
            return false;
        else if(!M[a])
            M[a]=true;
        else if(!M[N-1-a])
            M[N-1-a]=true;
    }
    bool f = true;
    for(int k=0;k<N;k++)
    {
        f = f && M[k];
    }
    return f;
}

int main() {
    M=new bool[1002];
    int num=0;
    scanf("%d",&num);
    while(num){
        int N=0;
        scanf("%d",&N);
        if(proc(N))
            printf("YES\n");
        else
            printf("NO\n");
        num--;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Code #2 (WA):

```
#include <cstdio>

bool* M;

bool proc(int N){
    for(int j=0;j<=N;j++){
        M[j]=false;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
        int a=0;
        scanf("%d",&a);
        if(a>=N)
            return false;
        else if(!M[a])
            M[a]=true;
        else if(!M[N-1-a])
            M[N-1-a]=true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

int main() {
    //Exactly same as code#1
}
```

Comment: You have a whole for loop in your first example that you don't have in your second example.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thank you, but that is obvious to me already. My problem is that I can't come up with any test case to differentiate these two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug has nothing to do with the algorithm itself—it's very possible both the algorithms are correct. But the second *implementation* is wrong.

When you reach a test case which should return `NO`, you exit the function prematurely. Which means there are some numbers from the current test case left unread in the input, which of course confuses further reading thoroughly. This means the bug only manifests when `T > 1`.

Comment: You are right! Such a simple bug! Thank you so much.